# How to diagnose Internal Server error on Lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd, fastcgi, logging

I have Lighttpd on Centos 5 with Fcgi and Memcached. Periodically, once per week or two i get internal server error 500 and i must manually restart lighttpd to get it to work again.

In my lighttpd config I've defined error log file:

```
server.errorlog             = "/home/lxadmin/httpd/lighttpd/error.log"
```

But when I open it, it has no rows for last days, only one month ago.

So my question is how to diagnose what is the issue and how to enable error log for my configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

```
nano /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

And put:

```
fastcgi.debug = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the problem is related with trouble connecting with the fcgi processes. Have you tried to strace lighttpd process when the internal server errors are happening? That should give you a clue of what's happening. Try something like this:

```
strace -p `pidof lighttpd` -o strace.output
```

then take a look at strace.output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And by the way, check if lighttpd has permissions to write to the error_log. Might be an issue as well.

Comment: How can I contact with you in private?

Comment: @Tomaszs: direct message me on twitter (@mramos29)